# Rails: select_tag

Tags: selected

i tried this here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

exactly this:

```
<%= collection_select(:sportlers, :sportlers_id, Sportler.all, :id, :name) %>
```

But there dont is written, how to get the selected value from the collection_select.

Im helpless, do you work with somethings like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `collection_select` will take the first two parameters, the object and the method, and use the values to make a hash, so in your case, you can access the values in your controllers like:

```
params[:sportlers][:sportlers_id]
```